# Changing drawer layout items

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-fragments

Code

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        fragment = new Fragment1();
    } else if (id == R.id.a) {
        fragment = new Fragment2();
    }else if (id == R.id.b) {
        fragment = new Fragment3();
    }else if (id == R.id.c) {
        fragment = new Fragment4();
    }else if (id == R.id.d) {
        fragment = new Fragment5();
    } else if (id == R.id.e) {
        fragment = new Fragment6();
    }else if (id == R.id.f) {
        fragment = new Fragment7();
    }else if (id == R.id.g) {
        fragment = new Fragment8();
    }else if (id == R.id.h) {
        fragment = new Fragment9();
    }else if (id == R.id.i) {
        fragment = new Fragment10();
    } else if (id == R.id.j) {
        fragment = new Fragment11();
    }else if (id == R.id.k) {
        fragment = new Fragment12();
    }

    //NOTE: Fragment changing code
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //Ya you can also globalize this variable :P
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I know that this is how to implement on click listeners to drawer. But i want the users data to decide which fragment comes where... I have a lot of data in firebase say a-z... And the user wants to show only vowels in drawer... How do i do that? Like maybe make the drawer act like a recyclerview or something? Can someone help me out please

Answer (score 1):

One way is to take all menu items in drawer and hide it logically using `setVisible()` method.

> **[setVisible()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean)) :**
>
> Sets the **visibility** of the menu item. Even if a menu item is not
>   visible, it may still be invoked via its shortcut *(to completely
>   disable an item, set it to invisible and disabled)*.

### Edit:

Use `setTitle()` method to change title of any menu item.

> **[setTitle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)) :**
>
> Change the title associated with this item.
>
> Some menu types do not sufficient space to show the full title, and
>   instead a condensed title is preferred.

Comment: The name of the items... how do i change them according to the users needs... Like i want to fetch the name from firebase and display it... how do i do that